# External HDD partitioning - Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I'm a Mac OS 10.8 user and I have a 1TB USB HDD partitioned before from my Mac in 3 parts. Now, I want to add another back-up partition but I'm not able to do it : I can't do anything on the HDD, not even verifying the disk. Here is a screenshot from Disk Utility in case it's helpful:

[image]

[image]

What should I do to be able to partition the disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Disk Utility, you can only resize partitions (without erasing them) if the partitioning scheme is GPT. Yours is MBR. Also, you can't verify this disk with Disk Utility.

You have some options (**always** do a full backup before doing anything!):

1. Erase the whole disk and re-partition it as GPT. In order to do this, you should select the right option (1, 2, 3, ... partitions) from the dropdown menu in the "Partition Layout" dropdown menu, then click on "Options..." and select the GPT scheme (like [this](http://www.bombich.com/software/docs/CCC/en.lproj/images/disk_format.gif)). In the future, you will able to shrink and resize partitions with Disk Utility.
2. Keep the MBR partition scheme with all your data and resize the drive using a capable tool like [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-advanced-partition-actions) (you could have to boot in a Linux environment, though).
3. Convert the partitions scheme from MBR to GPT (seems quite **risky** and it's untested by me): see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/495672/how-can-i-convert-a-mbr-partition-to-gpt-without-loss-of-data). If you succeed, you will be able to resize partitions using Disk Utility.