# How to partition hard drive from MBR to GPT for Windows 8.1 UEFI install

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, uefi, mbr, gpt

I just bought a new HP notebook (ProBook 450 G0) and it came preinstalled with Suse 11 Enterprise. Now this is the first time I've owned a system with an (U)EFI and I don't know how things work on this, I was used with the legacy BIOS and MBR. I have the following partitions on my HDD right now:

```
Disk 1 (MBR)
  + C:             FAT32      200MB Active
  + D:HP_RECOVERY  NTFS       4GB
  + *:HOME         EXT3       646GB
  + *:ROOT         EXT3       38GB
  + *:             Other      7GB
  + E:HP_TOOLS     FAT32      2GB
```

My first instinct was to do a zero format and partition it using Paragon Partition Magic (at least that's what I did on legacy BIOS).

What I want to do is I want to do a full UEFI Windows 8.1 install (my university provided me with a copy) and I don't know how to partition the HDD using GPT and not lose the two HP partitions needed for recovery and systems diagnostics.

Can someone please help me? I want to do this properly. Thanks! :)

P.S. It wouldn't let me login to my account, kept saying something about an auth error so I'm posting as a guest, sorry.

Comment: Don't partition anything just boot the disk into UEFI mode and allow Windows to so the work

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by wiping the entire drive after I've learned that the HP Tools partition can be recovered with a utility from HP and the recovery partition is essentially just a recovery of the SUSE system and that recovery disks can be ordered online from HP.

The only solution to preserve the factory defaults was to image or clone the HDD but I had nowhere to save the clone/image so I had no choice but to wipe the HDD clean.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself, and of course when you are toying with partitions and boot records, you had better be prepared to lose data. So, make an image of your disk before you proceed.

I know of a commandline way of converting a partition from MBR to GPT without data loss (**[GPTgen](http://gptgen.sourceforge.net/)**), but you should read the documentation thoroughly before attempting it. According to [MVP Shyam](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk)...

> It’s a very extensive tool but a bit complicated to run. According to the tool’s ‘read me’ file, the syntax of the tool is “gptgen [-w] \.\physicaldriveX”, where X is the drive number reported by the Disk Management console or the “list disk” command of the DISKPART utility. The -w option makes gptgen write the generated GUID partition tables to the disk, otherwise the primary table will be written to a file named “primary.img“, and the secondary table to “secondary.img“, in the directory that the program was invoked from. You can then use e.g. dd to write the tables to the disk.

On the other hand, there is a graphical program which purportedly is capable of converting a partition from MBR to GPT: **[AOMEI Partition Assistant Free](http://www.disk-partition.com/features/convert-mbr-gpt.html)**.

According to [their website](http://www.disk-partition.com/help/convert-gpt-mbr-disk.html), the steps in the graphical interface are simple:

> Step 1: Launch AOMEI Partition Assistant. Select the data disk you want to convert and right click it. And then select "Convert to GPT Disk" (or Convert to MBR Disk) in the drop-down menu.
>   Convert to GPT Disk
>
> Step 2: Click "OK" after confirming the operation.
>   Click OK
>
> Step 3: You can preview the conversion. To save the change, please click "Apply" on the toolbar.

Of course, be sure to read all documentation for this method, as well, before you proceed.

**There are other options**, as well, such as **[MiniTool Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html)** ([how-to](http://4sysops.com/archives/convert-mbr-to-gpt-without-data-loss/)), and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/495672/how-can-i-convert-a-mbr-partition-to-gpt-without-loss-of-data) is a *Super User* answer in which a guy answers his own question, having ended up using **[gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/)** (available on Windows, Mac, or Linux) on his Mac to convert a Mac partition from MBR to GPT without losing his data (though he backed up anyway). For a more in-depth how-to for *gdisk*, see [the developer's guide](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html).

### The Possible Snag

Now, as to how successful you will be at actually preserving the recovery functionality between these partitions, I cannot say. [Wolfgang Sommergut](http://4sysops.com/archives/convert-mbr-to-gpt-without-data-loss/) from 4sysops recommends:

> [I]f Windows is supposed to **boot up from the disk**, you are restricted to a particular partition scheme. Newer versions of Windows x64 only start from GPT disks on UEFI systems; in all other configurations, MBR is required. Thus, in most cases, you probably don’t want to convert boot disks. Doing so only makes sense if you accidentally installed a 64-bit Windows in BIOS emulation mode on a UEFI-capable PC.
>
> **Even in this scenario, it isn’t enough to convert the Windows partitions to GPT because the disks on UEFI systems have to be partitioned differently.** Hence, I recommend converting MBR to GPT **only on data drives**.

Good luck!

Comment: How in the world did this answer merit a downvote? I clearly worked on this and provided an informative answer for people having a similar issue.

Comment: You know, it is hard to build up any momentum to help anybody in an fine way, when, even when you work hard to provide a relevant and informative answer, people downvote you without explanation and the Asker omits accepting any answers. I can't even comment on OP's yet because I lack the cred -- and this kind of stuff has kept me sitting still for months. Doesn't make it more likely I will continue to volunteer my time here.