# Unable to install Ubuntu 16.04 on MBR drive in Legacy mode

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, mbr, gpt

A year ago i made the mistake of installing Windows in BIOS Mode which now has given me an MBR drive where i cannot create more than four primary partitions.

I'm trying to dual boot with Windows 10 and during Ubuntu installation, when i pick install alongside Windows i get the error

"too many primary partitions"

When i pick something else, i am not able to select a partition to install under nor am i able to create a new partition from the unallocated space.

These are my partitions as seen from Windows.

[image]

What can i do next to have Ubuntu running without having to wipe my entire disk?

Comment: "What can i do next to have Ubuntu running without having to wipe my entire disk?" - Use Windows 10 1703 new tool to convert to GPT.  It should be possible since you currently only have 3 partitions (2 logical and 1 extended).

Comment: If that doesn't work you will have to backup your partitions and use [gdisk](http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) instead. Here is a possible duplicate to your question: [How can I convert a MBR partition to GPT without loss of data?](https://superuser.com/questions/495672/how-can-i-convert-a-mbr-partition-to-gpt-without-loss-of-data)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misinterpreting the Windows tool, you've already got an extended partition and several logical partitions. (I *think* the screen shot shows that your `C:`, `D:`, and `E:` are logical partitions.) Thus, you can expand the extended partition and put at least some of Ubuntu in new logical partitions. An important caveat: Use Ubuntu's tools for this, not the Windows partitioner! The Windows tool tends to convert disks from standard MBR to MBR with [Logical Disk Manager (LDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager), aka "dynamic disks," atop that; and Ubuntu is next to impossible to install on such disks. Creating more logical partitions should work fine, with the caveat that you must boot the Ubuntu installer in BIOS mode, not in EFI mode. You will also need to use the "Something Else" partitioning option, since the "install alongside" option you say you've tried is not working. See [this AskUbuntu question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) for information on doing this.

Converting everything to GPT and EFI-mode booting with [MBR2GPT,](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) as Ramhound suggests, is another option. That's riskier but may provide more flexibility, since GPT doesn't use the awkward primary/extended/logical partition distinction. Of relevance to this: It looks like you've got 99.9 GB unallocated near the start of the disk and 18.16 GB at the end. The space at the start is positioned such that you can only create primary partitions there. It appears that you have two primary partitions and one extended partition, so you *should* be able to create *one* primary partition in that bigger spot. (This conclusion assumes that I'm interpreting the Windows screen shot correctly.) The space at the end would have to be allocated as logical partition(s) after expanding the extended partition. Moving your `G:` to the left would give you more flexibility, since then you could allocate the 99.9 GB space as logical partitions; but this move might disrupt your ability to boot Windows. If you do such a move, I'd use the Windows tool, since it's more likely to keep Windows bootable -- but I'd be sure to make a backup first, both because such moves are generically risky and because the Windows partitioning tools often damage disks that use extended and logical partitions.

In sum, if you can live with splitting Ubuntu across one 99.9 GB partition and one or more partitions that sum to 18 GB, sticking with the current layout and BIOS-mode booting is probably best. If you need to carve your space up differently, though, you'll have to decide between risky partition moving and resizing operations and a risky MBR-to-GPT conversion. Personally, I'd probably go with the latter, but that's a judgment call, and in my case, it's based on the fact that I'm very familiar with GPT partitioning and EFI-mode booting. (I wrote the GPT fdisk partitioning software and maintain the rEFInd boot manager.) If you decide to stick with MBR and BIOS-mode booting, that's quite understandable.